# Multiple instances of a DB Context in Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

In an ASP.Net 7 web api application, we have two sets of entities we need to build up with one set being built and persisted to the database, and the other set of entities being built in memory, but then discarded without persisting them so that we can preview the changes without saving. Both of these sets of entities are in the same database. We are using dependency injection to inject a DbContext into the controller when the controller is instantiated. In order to have separate "save contexts" such that one set of entities may be built without saving them while objects in the other "save contexts", I attempted to inject two instances of same DbContext into the controller.

```
public MyController(MyDbContext dbContext1, MyDbContext dbContext2)...
```

However, when I make changes to dbContext1 and the run dbContext1.SaveChanges(), I would expect that only the entities that I create and attach to dbContext1 are persisted, but what I have found is that the entities in dbContext2 are also persisted even though they are in a different instance of the DbContext.

```
public class MyController{
    MyDbContext _dbContext1;
    MyDbContext _dbContext2;

    public MyController(MyDbContext dbContext1, MyDBContext dbContext2){
        _dbContext1 = dbContext1;
        _dbContext2 = dbContext2;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        _dbContext1.MyEntities.Add(myEntity); // DO NOT want this entity saved

        _dbContext2.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity()); // DO want this entity saved

        // Running this SaveChanges persists entities in both _dbContext1 and _dbContext2
        // which is NOT what we want. We want only _dbContext2 entities to be saved
        await _dbContext2.SaveChangesAsync(); 
    }
}
```

How do I maintain two separate sets of entities such that a save in one does not trigger a save in the other DbContext?

Can I still use dependency injection to do that, or do I have to manually manage the DbContexts?

Do I somehow use transactions within the same DbContext to manage different sets of entities?

Comment: Try checking result of `Object.ReferenceEquals(_dbContext1, _dbContext2)`.

Comment: P.S. " so that we can preview the changes without saving" - why exactly is there any reason you can't do it using the same context?

Comment: This seems like a code smell to me, why don't you want that entity saved? If you don't want it saved, then don't add it to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `_dbContext1` and `_dbContext2` are the same instance. EF's default `DbContext` service-factory only creates a single `DbContext` instance per request-scope, and that instance is shared by all objects that use an injected `DbContext` in that same request scope.

If you want multiple DbContexts you need to use `IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>` - and you will also need to manage the lifetime of those DbContexts yourself (all you need is a `using()` block) as ASP.NET will not clean-up any DbContexts created via a factory.

Change your code to this:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbFactory;

    public MyController( IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbFactory )
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbFactory));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(MyEntity myEntity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using( MyDbContext db1 = this.dbFactory.CreateDbContext() )
        using( MyDbContext db2 = this.dbFactory.CreateDbContext() )
        {
            db1.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);
            db2.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity());

            await db1.SaveChangeAsync(cancellationToken);
            await db2.SaveChangeAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first paragraph was the key for me to understand the issue. I changed my code and it worked. There was one thing I needed that @guru-stron provided which was the line to use to add the DbContextFactory to build.Services at startup. I didn't know that I could chain two using statements in like you did in the AddAsync. That was helpful to learn. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah - I forgot about the need to call `.AddDbContextFactory` - I thought that `.AddDbContext` implicitly also called `AddDbContextFactory` internally, but apparently not :)

Answer (score 1):

So without diving into WHY do you want to do this (I sense some [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) going on here) from pure technical standpoint of view one of the solutions would be using [`IDbContextFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor). To do that you will need to set it up in the DI:

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => ...);
```

And then inject into the controller:

```cs
public class MyController{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _dbFactory;

    public MyController(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbFactory){
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        using MyDbContext db1 = this.dbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        using MyDbContext db2 = this.dbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Context created "manually" via factory should be disposed
2. `AddDbContextFactory` allows resolving the context itself, so you can follow different patterns for different cases:

```cs
public class MyController{
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _dbFactory;

    public MyController(
        MyDbContext dbContext, 
        IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> dbFactory){
        // ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        using MyDbContext tmpCtx = this.dbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        // use tmpCtx and _dbContext for different purposes 
    }
}
```

3. There are some other options (with some caveats depending on the application structure) - you can register the context as transient (by providing corresponding parameter for `AddDbContext`) or use change tracker to clear the changes (`dbContext1.ChangeTracker.Clear();`) but without understanding WHY it is hard to tell what would be the best one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked the other one as the answer because it gave me the insight I needed, but your answer helped tell me how to set up the dependency injection for the DbContextFactory at startup time. Thanks for the help. Guru Stron

Comment: @Brian was glad to help! Feel free to upvote then (if not already)!